# BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint is not returning WWW-Authenticate header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm playing with Spring Security and trying to understand how it works. I was trying to set the BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint as the response emitter in case of an unauthorized attempt to my API. So this is how I done it:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                //.and()
                //.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }
```

The response I'm obtaining is this one:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-02-05T20:00:26.066+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/find/shipmentNumber/1"
}
```

And no WWW-Authenticate header.

I was checking the source code for the BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint and it's supossed to add the mentioned header:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, InitializingBean {

    private String realmName;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.hasText(this.realmName, "realmName must be specified");
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + this.realmName + "\"");
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
    }

    public String getRealmName() {
        return this.realmName;
    }

    public void setRealmName(String realmName) {
        this.realmName = realmName;
    }

}
```

However, it works if I do it this way:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                //.addFilter(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }
```

Can someone please explain why is not working with the first approach? Is using another implementation of AuthenticationEntryPoint?

Comment: i dont really understand why you are adding filters that are already in the filter chain.

Comment: @Toerktumlare the first two, are extensions of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and BasicAuthenticationFilter respectively. The ExceptionTranslationFilter, I thought I had to add it... Where can I find the default list of filters?

Comment: here you can read what the default configuration is https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-hello-auto-configuration

Comment: here is the filter ordering https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-security-filters

Comment: and if you want to try out basic username/password you start reading here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-unpwd

Comment: when you for instance add `formLogin()` spring security will add in the filters that are needed for that type of authentication. Its not that you build your authentication method using filters.